# Camel HTTP file upload

Tags: java, http, apache-camel

I'm trying to write a Camel route that processes an uploaded csv file. The route itself is working, but rather than just converting the uploaded file to a String array, it processes something like the following (with each line becoming part of the array)

------WebKitFormBoundaryjJXGAXwz14r5Sa40
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="codes.csv"; filename="codes.csv"
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel

AAAAAAAAAA
1111111111
2222222222
cccccccccc
------WebKitFormBoundaryjJXGAXwz14r5Sa40--

The route looks like this:

```
from("restlet:http://0.0.0.0:{{restlet.port.secure}}/codes/{" + Constants.CAMPAIGN_ID + "}/upload?restletMethod=PUT")
            .routeId("codeUploadCsv")
            .unmarshal()
            .csv()
            .split(body())
            .to("activemq:queue:code.in");
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to just pull the file out of the post data?

Comment: This is called multipart request and must be handled by special processor. You can either write custom body processor to split parts of request or use jetty component that supports multipart file uploads.